# Reference request for "higher order" adjoint functors?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories, adjoint-functors, derived-functors

Assume all the categories here are abelian and the functors are additive. Given functors $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G : \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$, we say that they are an adjoint pair if there is a natural bijection
$$
\text{Hom}(F(a), b) \simeq \text{Hom}(a, G(b)).
$$
Is there a term for when there is a natural bijection of Ext groups,
$$
\text{Ext}^{i}(F(a), b) \simeq \text{Ext}^{i}(a, G(b))?
$$
Further, since $F$ may fail to be left exact and $G$ may fail to be right exact, is there a term for when the derived functors are adjoint?

This has come up in a few topics I am studying, but results are generally just stated as known. I'm interested at looking at this in the general case, but I don't know what the terminology is to look for. Is there a standard reference that covers this, or even just a name for these functors?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657272/significance-of-adjoint-relationship-with-ext-instead-of-hom) might be related.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a homological version of an enriched adjunction ? (like $R\hom (F(-), -) \cong R\hom(-,G(-))$ ?)